# Слова "является", "явился" и "проявление" однокоренные?

Tags: словообразование, однокоренные-слова

Слова "является", "явился" и "проявление" однокоренные?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Да, это однокоренные слова из одного словообразовательного гнезда.

Явить-явиться - являться (черед.в/вл )

явить-являть (черед.в/вл)- проявлять-проявление

Вы сомневаетесь, не являются ли глаголы "является"и "явился" формами одного слова? Нет, не являются, они образованы от глаголов разного вида: является от являться, а явился от явиться. Формы глагола - глаголы с изменением непостоянных признаков -лица, числа, времени и наклонения, а вид - признак постоянный, глаголы разного вида имеют разные оттенки значения, разные морфемы (приставки и суффиксы)

Вот если бы было является и являлся, являемся; явился,явилась,явились, явится - это формы, а названные слова - разные слова, однокоренные.

Answer (score 1):

По Тихонову [является - являться - **явл**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), [явился - явиться - **яв**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), [проявление - **проявл**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Но очевидно, что у всех слов в основе лежит морфема - **яв**

***является - явился*** не только однокоренные, это разные видовременные формы одного и того же глагола **являться/явиться**

также ***явка, заявление, явь, наяву, отъявленный***

пиявка... (нет, нет, шучу)

Comment: Являться и явиться — это глаголы разного вида, а значит, является и явился — это не просто «разные временные формы одного и того же глагола». Более того, непонятно, что тогда такое Л в _являться_, если корень -яв-.

Comment: думаю, что тонкости различения видов для ответа на заданный вопрос неактуальны, потому обе формы приведены как пара, что такое Л - это уже следующий вопрос

Comment: а мне кажется, что некорректно называть разные видовременные формы разными временными формами. Л — каким бы вопросом он ни был — ставит под сомнение выделение корня -яв-, поэтому осветить его в ответе, я думаю, стоит.

Comment: ошибка, исправил... что касается необходимости пояснений присутствия Л, в этом случае исключение из корня приставки про- также требует пояснений, но всё это выходит за рамки вопроса

Comment: явление чередования мягких губных фонем с сочетанием губная+Л при образовании производных форм от инфинитивов на -ить рассматривается работе [Мусатова В.Н. "Русский язык. Морфемика. Морфонология. Словообразование"](http://goo.gl/H9aaqC)

Comment: Да, замечательно. Упомянув, что -явл- — это позиционный вариант корня -яв-, вы бы избавили себя и вопрошающего от соответствующих вопросов. А мы ведь создаем библиотеку вопросов и ответов, которые должны помогать, так? ;) (Если что, моя критика, даже скорее советы, призвана помочь в составлении хорошего ответа, а вовсе не обидеть отвечающего придирками. Пожалуйста, не расстраивайтесь из-за комментариев! :))

Comment: по-моему ввод нового термина "позиционный вариант" может породить новые вопросы )))

Comment: вариант корня, который проявляет себя в определенных позициях, должно быть понятней — суть не в формулировке, а в месседже, который я хочу донести )

Comment: вариант текста без заблокированных страниц - [Мусатов В.Н. "Русский язык. Морфемика. Морфонология. Словообразование"](http://goo.gl/mHnda6)